# rich:dataTable - with list jsf - put list into columns and rows

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I would like to put list of objects into rich:dataTable, and put element in table with 5 rows and 3 columns

```
<rich:dataTable id="x" rows="5" columns="3" value="#{a.lst}" var="obj" columnsWidth="200px,200px,200px">
```

Is there anything like

```
<rich:cell>
```

there? This seems to be a common issue, so I hope there is support for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use rich:dataGrid which allows you specify columns